# save() ignores the "updateAt" field change

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, mocha.js

So, I am trying to (unit) test some of the functions using **mongoose** and **mocha**. The problem is that as I try to `save( )` the schema, the *updatedAt* field gets rewritten to the current time.

I.e. I have the following applicant

```
const applicant: DataModel = new DataSchema({
        "user_name": "user_notifying2rejected",
        "uuid": "10",
        "status": "notifying_user",
        "request_origin": "127.0.0.10"
});
```

Then, I do

```
applicant.updatedAt = new Date(new Date() - 2.592e+8);
```

When I do `console.log(applicant.updateAt)`, I get the correct necessary date, which is basically "3 days ago".

Then, as usual, I save that to the database using mongoose:

```
await application.save();
```

However, when I try to validate the document (that I have just saved), I instead get the following:

```
{
    createdAt: 2018-05-28T16:43:31.648Z,
    updatedAt: 2018-05-28T16:43:31.648Z,
    user_name: 'user_notifying2rejected',
    uuid: '10',
    request_origin: '127.0.0.10',
    _id: 5b0c31b06698440017d1593e,
    status: 'notifying_user'
}
```

And now *updatedAt* is today's date, not "3 days ago" as I want to it be. How to stop **mongoose** or **mongoose.save** from changing/overwriting my *updatedAt* field?

Here is the Schema. Let me know if you need anything else.

**Schema**

```
const DataSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    user_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    uuid: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: "unprocessed"
    },
    request_origin: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
},
{
    timestamps: { createdAt: "createdAt", updatedAt: "updatedAt" }
});
```

Comment: You have timestamps turned on for the schema. If you don't want them then turn them off. Read the referenced link for an understanding of how they actually work.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you use `await application.save();` if you change updateAt in **applicant** document?